# Menu navigation closing itself

Tags: html, css

Here's my code for the navigation menu

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://4343/wordpress/index.php/blogs/">MUSIC</a>
            </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://1343.64.5/wordpress/index.php/submit/">SUBMIT</a>
            </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="http://192.16834364.5/wordpress/index.php/contact/">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

When i'm viewing my website on mobile and trying to click on the menu it's closing itself. it opens(shows the dropdown with items) for a second then closes itself. i'm not able to figure out why it's happening, anyone can help me out here?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We can't help without code, Please add code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: you  mean the html code?

Comment: Include all code related to your issue.

Comment: At least add script for debugging.